# How to detect ESC in string using Boost regex

Tags: c++, boost

I need to determine if a file is PCL encoded.  So I am looking at the first line to see if it begins with an ESC character.  If you know a better way feel free to suggest.  Here is my code:

```
bool pclFlag = false;
if (containStr(jobLine, "^\\e")) {
   pclFlag=true;
}

bool containStr(const string& s, const string& re)
{
   static const boost::regex e(re);
   return regex_match(s, e);
}
```

pclFlag does not get set to true.

Comment: Why use a regex for this? Just check if the first character is an escape: `jobLine[0] == '\x1b'`

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `boost::regex e` to be static, which means it will only get initialized the very first time your function is called.  If your search here is *not* the first call, it will be searching for whatever string was passed in the first call.

regex_match must match the *entire* string.  Try adding ".*" (dot star) to the end of your regex.

**Important**
Note that the result is true only if the expression matches the **whole** of the input sequence. If you want to search for an expression somewhere within the sequence then use regex_search. If you want to match a prefix of the character string then use regex_search with the flag match_continuous set.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html

@JoachimPileborg is right...  `if (jobline[0] == 0x1B) {}` is much easier.

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion by Joachim Pileborg does work, but for my own education I would like to get my code to work.  I changed static const to just be const, but pclFlag still stays false.

Comment: Oh, silly me...  I should have read the big bubble on the page I was referencing.  Let me update that answer. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my oversight about the difference between regex_match and regex_search.  Changing to regex_search fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Regex seems like overkill if all you want to do is see if a string starts with a certain character.

```
bool pclFlag = jobLine.length() > 0 && jobLine[0] == '\033';
```

You could also use Boost string algorithms:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

bool pclFlag = jobLine.starts_with("\033");
```

If you're looking to see if a string contains an escape anywhere in the string:

```
bool pclFlag = jobLine.find('\033') != npos;
```

Comment: This suggestion was bade as a comment to the original question and also included in my own answer above (with credit).

Comment: @Brian Comments are not answers. Plus he gives several implementation options.